# Adicionar query parameters ao redirect url no processo de autorização Implicit Flow

Tags: api, oauth2

Durante o processo de autorização de uma aplicação via `Implicit Flow` no Jasmin é possível passar alguma informação extra no pedido de forma a que esta seja incluída no `redirect uri` quando este for chamado?

Já testei com `query parameters` no próprio `redirect uri` mas o Jasmin falha com a mensagem `invalid redirect uri` o que leva-me a supor que o Jasmin faz uma comparação directa entre o endereço passado por nós e o que está configurado no nitrogen.

O que se pretende com este processo é adicionar algum contexto ao processo para ser mais fácil fazer o mapeamento quando o redirect for executado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O fluxo de autenticação implicit serve para ser usado em aplicações cliente que tipicamente não conseguem manter de forma segura o *Client Secret* porque o codigo está todo diponivel no lado do cliente.

Este fluxo aceita como parametros:

- **client_id** Identificador fornecido pelo nitrogem
- **redirect_uri** Endereço para onde a aplicação deve ser redereiconada. Fornecido pelo nitrogem
- **scope** Scope definido para a aplicação "Interno"

Relativamente ao seu problema. Não pode passar um redirect_uri diferente do que indicou no registo da aplicação no nitrogen, porque o servidor de identidade vai validar se o que passou no pedido é igual ao que está associado a sua aplicação. Questão de segurança.

Comment: Neste caso não faz sentido usar `Implicit Flow` pelo que só me resta usar `Client Credentials` uma vez que não há mais opções. O problema neste caso é que obriga a uma quantidade relativamente grande de passos manuais como associar a aplicação à subscrição, copiar o subscription id e account id e garantir que tudo bate certo. Não existe nenhuma alternativa mais simples para autorizar aplicações externas a acederem à minha subscrição de Jasmin?

Comment: Não sabendo o que quer fazer nem o tipo de aplicação deve ter em atenção que este fluxo expõe os segredos aos utilizadores. é um fluxo usado tipicamente em cenários Maquina-Maquina.

Comment: O que pretendo é relativamente trivial: tenho um serviço que disponibilizo a clientes Jasmin para automatização de processos. Para isso pretendo utilizar a web API do Jasmin para ler alguma informação. Para ter acesso a essa informação é preciso que o cliente autorize o meu serviço a aceder à sua subscrição. Nem `Implicit Flow` nem `Client Credentials` fazem sentido pelo que descreveu pelo que resta `Application Grant` que não está disponível. Também existe o problema de saber quais são os `subscription id` e `account id` para a Web API que não estão disponíveis em nenhuma altura do processo.

Comment: Por partes, se tem uma web app o fluxo é o `Implicit flow`. Não entendo o qie passar mais no pedido. O objetivo é ter autorização para poder a seguir fazer os pedidod à aplicação.

A `subscription id` e `account id` devem ser configuradas na app.